# update ros wiki link to my package after renaming it

Tags: ros, package, documentation, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to everyone.

I have successfully added my package to rosdistro for indigo and kinetic. I renamed the directory name to match the package name I gave to it..

Should I do something more, so that the ros documentation status in ros wiki link to be updated?
Because it's still says

> "Cannot load information on name:
> muse_bldc_motor_drive, distro: indigo,
> which means that it is not yet in our
> index. Please see this page for
> information on how to submit your
> repository to our index."

Here is my repository https://bitbucket.org/muserobotics/muse_ros_package/src/d6a6c7d93144?at=master
Here is the documentation link I have already wrote http://wiki.ros.org/muse_bldc_motor_drive

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269226/update-ros-wiki-link-to-my-package-after-renaming-it/) by [MariaKrgr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26662/mariakrgr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would appear that the [doc job](http://build.ros.org/view/Idoc/job/Idoc__muse_bldc_motor_drive__ubuntu_trusty_amd64) for your package ran *before* you changed the name from `muse` to `muse_bldc_motor_driver` (from [here](http://build.ros.org/view/Idoc/job/Idoc__muse_bldc_motor_drive__ubuntu_trusty_amd64/1/console#console-section-1)):

> ```
> Invoking '. /opt/ros/indigo/setup.sh && PYTHONIOENCODING=utf_8 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 catkin_make_isolated --install --cmake-args -DCATKIN_SKIP_TESTING=1 --catkin-make-args -j1' in '/tmp/catkin_workspace'
> ```

```
...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
~~  - muse
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I change the `PackageHeader(..)` argument on your wiki page from `muse_bldc_motor_drive` to `muse`, I see the expected info rendered:

[image: muse instead of muse_bldc_motor_drive]

The doc job is triggered by changes to your repository, so you could commit and push some arbitrary change to get it to run again. That should make the package header appear on your wiki page.

Note however that doc jobs are only run once every three days, so it could take some time for the changes to become visible.

---

Edit: I would actually suggest you make some other changes to your repository, so these could be used to trigger the doc job again instead of some arbitrary change. As follows:

1. remove the `src/CMakeLists.txt` link: it's not supposed to be versioned, it is (re)created automatically be Catkin on every user's machine. Additionally, having an extra `CMakeLists.txt` in there could cause some hard-to-diagnose errors as there will be now two files pointing to `/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake` in the workspace.
2. move the contents of `src/muse_bldc_motor_drive` to the root of the repository: the `src/` folder would appear to be the actual *source space* of your Catkin workspace, which is normally not versioned.
3. remove the contents of the `muse_bldc_motor_drive/doc/html` directory: those files get rebuild by the ROS doc job on every build, so there is no need to include them in the repository. Additionally, users can easily regenerate them locally, reducing maintenance for you as you don't need to keep them up-to-date with the code in the repository.
4. (minor): locations specified in your `CMakeLists.txt` are already relative to the location of that `CMakeLists.txt`, so there is no need to do things like `${MUSE_ROS_PATH}/..`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MariaKrgr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26662/mariakrgr/) on 2017-08-22**:
thank you for the advices!
I will be waiting for three days to see any rebuild in doc jobs..

**Comment by [MariaKrgr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26662/mariakrgr/) on 2017-08-24**:
Just for the record, package documentation was rebuild and updated within 3 days.